# Laravel pass additional parameters into has

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Lets say I have a relationship on a model like this

```
public function currentInvoices($time = 'current'){
        switch ($time) {
            case 'current':
                $start = Carbon::create()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $end = Carbon::create()->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            break;
            case 'lastMonth':
                $start = Carbon::create()->subMonth()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $end = Carbon::create()->subMonth()->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            break;
            default:
                $start = Carbon::create()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $end = Carbon::create()->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }

        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Models\Invoices',
            'App\Models\Tenancies\Tenancies',
            'linked_tenant_id', // Foreign key on Tenancies table...
            'tenant_id', // Foreign key on invoices table...
            'id', // Local key on tenants table...
            'id' // Local key on tenancies table...
        )->where('invoices.start_date','>=',$start)->where('invoices.end_date','<=',$end);
    }
```

How would I pass an argument when using eloquents `has`. For example, this is what i'm trying to achieve

```
$tenantCompany = $tenantCompany->has('currentInvoices','lastMonth');
```

Is it possible to pass a second argument into eloquents `has` function? If not any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereHas`

```php
$tenantCompany = $tenantCompany->whereHas('currentInvoices', function($query) use($start_date, $end_date {
    $query->where('start_date', '>=', $start_date)->where('end_date', '<=', $end_date);
})->get();
```

More about relationship methods: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion, but this isn't really what i'm looking for. I was looking at a way to run the switch statement inside my model, so I need to be able to call the `has` eloquent function and pass an argument into it.

Comment: @S_R you could create 2 separate relations or 2 separate queries. But you shouldn't pass parameters to your relations. It's just not how it should work.

Comment: @S_R your second case is to use a variable inside your class. And create a setter for it and just change it all the time. But seems like a bad solution for me

Comment: As it doesn't seem achievable the way I want to do it, I have just ran a whereHas in the controller as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do it like this

```
public function invoices(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Models\Invoices',
            'App\Models\Tenancies\Tenancies',
            'linked_tenant_id', // Foreign key on Tenancies table...
            'tenant_id', // Foreign key on invoices table...
            'id', // Local key on tenants table...
            'id' // Local key on tenancies table...
        );
}

public function currentInvoices(){
    $start = Carbon::create()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $end = Carbon::create()->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    return $this->invoices()->where('invoices.start_date','>=',$start)
                            ->where('invoices.end_date','<=',$end);
}

public function lastMonthInvoices(){
    $start = Carbon::create()->subMonth()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $end = Carbon::create()->subMonth()->endOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    return $this->invoices()->where('invoices.start_date','>=',$start)
                            ->where('invoices.end_date','<=',$end);
}
```

Now fetch it like this

```
$tenantCompany = $tenantCompany->has('lastMonthInvoices');
```

Comment: This is how I did it initially, but the name `currentInvoices` has to stay the same for a loop in blade. Thanks for the suggestion.